# what's nodeJS suit for? use nodeJS to do the automate web UI testing?

Tags: testing, node.js, web

everyone

do you think nodeJS suit for the web UI automate testing?
I　don't think so. 
first, nodeJS base on V8 engine, so how to test the issue on IE6-8?also how about other 
no web-kit based browser?
second, what's nodeJS suit for?

Answer (score 1):

What are you talking about? NodeJS is designed for writing *SERVERS*, not clients. It has nothing to do with browsers.

Imho NodeJS is the best choice for writing high traffic web servers. Also together with websockets it is also very good choice. And it is the future of web designing since the unification of language used in client's side and server's side.

Comment: its not the best choice for high traffic web servers

Answer (score 1):

You can use nodeJS to connect to Selenium and do automated UI tests, Soda (https://github.com/testingbot/soda) supports this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a node.js based headless browser to automate UI tests, check out [zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/).  If you want to create a UI test suite that runs against different browsers, I'd highly recommend [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: Yep, Selenium is better choice to do the automation testing~